# Проблема вывода строки методом цикла по символам на Си

Tags: c, for, while

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(char *text) {
  int i = 0;
  for(int c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar()) {text[i] = c; i++;}
}

void print(char *text) {
  for(int i = 0; text[i] != EOF; i++) {putchar(text[i]);}
}

int main() {
  char in[50];
  input(in);
  print(in);
}
```

Ввод input работает, но цикл вывода по символьно работает сумасшедше: выводит лишь первый символ, бывает два или три, не знаю от чего это зависит.
Пробовал выводить без цикла, просто написал 5 раз:

> printf("%c", x[1..5])

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

результат такой-же — неудачный.
Написал:

> printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", x[0], x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qIEW.jpg), x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5])

в этот раз вывелось всё правильно.
Проблему я решил, помимо %c существует %s, но кто знает, с чем связанно то, что при цикле вывода каждого символа выводит один-три символа??

До этого, писал **однострочный** импут и ввод, **тут проблем не было**:

```
void print_str(char *text) {
    for(int x = 0; text[x] != '\n'; x++) {printf("%c", text[x]);}
}

void input_str(char *text) {
    int len=0;
    for (char a; a != '\n'; len++) {
        scanf("%c", &a);
        text[len] = a;
    }
}
```

**Если кто-то знает**, почему так работает, объясните или дайте сурс где описана данная ситуация, пытался разобраться сам, не понимаю..

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вопрос первый: как вы *заканчивали* ввод? Вопрос второй: почему вы пытаетесь использовать для ограничения вывода EOF?  ngv более что вы его в массив не вносите :) Допишите нулевой символ в конце введенной строки, и проверяйте его при выводе.

Comment: В input_str нужно еще len передавать, ограничить ввод размером массива. И при нажатии Enter заканчивать ввод, добавляя 0 в конце. Это StringZ форма хранения строк. Т.е. в Си в конце строки рекомендуют ставить 0. И функции string.h рассчитывают на это ;)  'Input String\0'

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что ошибка заключается в EOF, который работает очень странно, недавно, писал код по счёту количества символов в вводе и проверка на EOF препятствовала последующему циклу:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != 'EOF') {
    ...
} 
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {...}
```

В итоге цикл выводился лишь один раз, но стоило мне сменить *'EOF'* на *'\n'* и проблема решилась, цикл заработал, всё стабильно, ещё наткнулся на [интересную статью](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/491700) на хабе, кому интересно, прочитаете.

Хочу сказать спасибо тем, кто пытался мне помочь, я почти сразу нашёл ответ и заключается он в том, что в Си существует помимо %c (вывода символа) %s (вывода строки) и, почему-то, вывод строки по-символьно работал некорректно из-за EOF-а.

**FrancNet** предположил, что нужно передавать не только список, но и количество символов, но этого не нужно, если в конце строки есть '\0'.
А вот и та самая функция:

```
void input(char *text) {
    int i = 0;
    //for(int c = getchar();(c != EOF & c != '\n'); c = getchar()) {text[i] = c; i++;}
    //text[i] = '\0';
    for(int c = getchar();c != EOF; c = getchar()) {text[i] = c; i++;}
    text[i-1] = '\0';  // If last char == \n i fix this
}
```